# Run jenkins slave nodes on an eks cluster by kubernetes plugin

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I am using Jenkins Kubernetes plugin and i have been trying to connect to the eks cluster via Jenkins.my jenkins-master is running on a standalone server and eks is running separately.i want the slave nodes to be provisioned as pods in the cluster.however when i use the Kubernetes plugin in my case to connect to the cluster using the kubeconfig file,it gives me this error.

`Error testing connection : Failure executing: GET at: https://*******/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods. Message: Forbidden! User arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:******:cluster/******* doesn't have permission. pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default".`

i have tried creating roles and rolebinding,which are given below but still i am unable to provision to eks cluster

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-pods
  namespace: default # your namespace
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: system:anonymous # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role #this must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: pod-reader # this must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

This is the role-binding i created and this is the error i am still getting
[image]

Comment: As it is a permissions issue - did you see [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/specify-service-account-role.html)?